# how to remove particular objects from array iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

i have  an string of these words between irregular spaces

```
 "gbpjpy buy 132.00/15  131.95 update close at 132.40 close at 132.40 120+ gbpjpy buy 132.00/15 131.50 45 new 90 120+       gpbusd buy    update HIT 40 PIPS HIT 110 PIPS  gpbusd buy   BREAK EVEN update HIT 100+  gpbusd buy 1.5500/25 1.5455  new 40 100+  gpbusd buy    update CLOSE 0 TO 10 PIPS N   gpbusd buy 1.5335/50 1.5320  new 40 80+  gpbusd buy    update     15-20 PIPS CLOSE KEEP OPEN gpbusd buy 1.5530/50     1.5505 update HIT 80 KEEP OPEN gpbusd buy 1.5530/50 1.5465  new 40 80 100+"
```

In this string there are irregular spaces ?can anybody tell a proper way to remove those spaces ?

Comment: Can you reformat your request...

Comment: sorry for the complicated question

Comment: My main question was to remain particular things like irregular spaces ,symbols etc from a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

or you can do this also `[yourArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];`
look at the header files of `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 4):

```
[yourArray removeObject:@"object"];
```

yourArray must be muttable

Answer (score 0):

I myself found an answer may this will help othe rpeople too:My question code had irregular spaces between items, this will remove all spaces and store items in array

```
 NSString *str=@"mango        apple    banana grapes    pineapple";
    NSRange match;  

  arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


while(str.length>0)
{
match = [str rangeOfString: @" "];
    if(match.location>=str.length)
    {
        [arr addObject:str];
        break;
    }
NSString *str2=[str substringToIndex:match.location];
str=[str substringFromIndex:match.location+1];
    if(str2.length==0)
    {
        continue;   
    }
[arr addObject:str2];
}
NSLog(@"array is %@",arr);    //here is your array
```